# How does query with multiple where condition work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table account_config where I keep key-value configs for accounts with columns:

1. id - pk
2. account_id - fk
3. key
4. value

Table may have configs for thousands of accounts, but for each account it may have 10-20 configs max. I am using query:

```
select id, key, value from account_config t where t.account_id = ? and t.key = ?;
```

I already have index for account_id field, do I need another index for *key* field here? Will second filter (key = ?) apply to already filtered result set (account_id = ?) or it scans whole table?

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: The answer depends on many things, among them the selectivity of each condition.

Comment: On a side note: Ask yourself whether it is really necessary to work with a key/value table. They are much slower than plain columns in an account table and can make it hard to keep your data consistent considering types and optional vs. obligatory attributes.

Comment: "The answer depends on many things, among them the selectivity of each condition." This is false since PostGreSQL has add the clause INCLUDE copyied from Mircosoft SQL Server to have covering indexes that does not required a double access index + table; In the given example the perfect index will be CREATE IDNEX X ON account_config (account_id, key) INCLUDE (value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are used when only a small percentage of the table's rows get accessed and the index helps finding those rows quickly.

You say there are thousands of accounts in your table, each with 10 to 20 rows.

Let's say there are 3000 accounts and 45,000 rows in your table, then accessing data via an index on the account ID means with the index we access about 0,03 % of the rows to find the one row in question. That makes it extremely likely that the index will be used.

Of course, if there were an index on `(account_id, key)`, that index would be preferred, as we would only have to read one row from the table which the index points to.

So, yes, your index should suffice for the query shown, but if you want to get this faster, then provide the two-column index.

Comment: "Indexes are used when only a small percentage of the table's rows get accessed" this is false since PostGreSQL has add the clause INCLUDE copyied from Mircosoft SQL Server to have covering indexes that does not required a double access index + table

Comment: @SQLpro: You are right, the statement is not precise. But I think it suffices for the explanation. It is about the small percentage of data access, but with covering indexes, the table itself is no longer involved. This was the same, by the way, before the `INCLUDE` clause got introduced, because a covering index was just a normal index that included all columns used in the query then.

Comment: In fact INCLUDE has some avantages on indexes because the columns in the include part does not participates to the internal ordering of the index and minimize the INSERT/UPDATE overload